# Limit APC opcode caching to specific sites? Nginx + PHP-FPM + APC

Tags: nginx, php5, php-fpm

Is there any way to enable/disable APC on a per virtual host basis? I'd rather not use precious apc shared memory on caching my PHPmyAdmin subdomain or lesser used sites. Setup is Nginx, php-fpm, and apc.

From what I've read the filter setting of APC cannot match against full path so I am looking for some other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to set up two separate pools of php "workers" in your `php-fpm.conf`, [each using a different php_defines](http://php-fpm.org/wiki/Configuration_File) as well as a different port.  One would have APC enabled, one would not.  How to enable or disable APC would depend on if you built it into the PHP executable or not.  If it is built in, you'd add `apc.enabled=0` in one php_defines to disable it in that worker pool.  Otherwise, you'd remove the `extension=apc.so` from your default .ini file and move it into one of the php_defines to enable it in that worker pool.

In nginix, you should be able to set which worker pool gets used on a per-`location` basis by putting the correct port in `fastcgi_pass`.  You could test if its working or not by creating a small script calling phpinfo() in each location and checking the output for APC.

Comment: Happy to hear there's support for multiple pools. I thought that I might have to install php-fpm twice and rename the second instance and do some other nastiness. I get the gist and will check the documentation for specifics. Do you have any additional reference material? Thanks!

Comment: I think the APC flag is called apc.enabled=0